# How to specify transition animations for show and hide react-chartjs-2

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-chartjs-2

I am having trouble editing the show and hide transition animation options. The documentation for this part of the animations section on chartjs is lacking. I want full control of the show and hide animations, but can't seem to figure it out or find examples that work for me.

I tried changing the easing function of the hide property in *animations* and *transitions* but it didn't work. Accessing the property though the chart context / chartRef.current also didn't seem to work. I know either of these methods would work if done properly.

[gif of chart as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt5rH.gif)

This is definitely not how I'm suppose to do it, but close to what it should look like, slide, in and out, linear. A snippet from the options config:

```
animation: {
    y: {
        duration:4000,
        from:1000,
        easing:'linear'
        delay:400,
        loop:true,
    }
}
```